# What is the faster way to count occurrences of equal sublists in a nested list?

Tags: python

I have a list of lists in Python and I want to (as fastly as possible : very important...) append to each sublist the number of time it appear into the nested list.

I have done that with some `pandas` data-frame, but this seems to be very slow and I need to run this lines on very very large scale. *I am completely willing to sacrifice nice-reading code to efficient one.*

So for instance my nested list is here:

```
l = [[1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 2] ,[1, 3, 5]]
```

I need to have:

```
res = [[1, 3, 2, 2], [1, 3, 5, 1]]
```

**EDIT**

Order in `res` does not matter at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If order does not matter you could use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) with [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/), as a variant of @Chris_Rands solution:

```
from collections import Counter

l = [[1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 2] ,[1, 3, 5]]

result = [[*t, count] for t, count in Counter(map(tuple, l)).items()]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 3, 5, 1], [1, 3, 2, 2]]
```

Comment: This is a reasonable (although mostly cosmetic) variant of my solution, assuming Python 3 of course

Answer (score 8):

This is quite an odd output to *want* but it is of course possible. I suggest using `collections.Counter()`, no doubt others will make different suggestions and a `timeit` style comparison would reveal the fastest of course for particular data sets:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l = [[1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 2] ,[1, 3, 5]]
>>> [list(k) + [v] for k, v in Counter(map(tuple,l)).items()]
[[1, 3, 2, 2], [1, 3, 5, 1]]
```

Note to preserve the insertion order prior to CPython 3.6 / Python 3.7, use [the `OrderedCounter` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes).

Answer (score 1):

If `numpy` is an option, you could use [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) setting axis to `0` and `return_counts` to `True`, and concatenate the unique rows and counts using [`np.vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html):

```
l = np.array([[1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 2] ,[1, 3, 5]])
x, c = np.unique(l, axis=0, return_counts=True)
np.vstack([x.T,c]).T

array([[1, 3, 2, 2],
       [1, 3, 5, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your items are mutable objects and you have to convert them to an immutable object to be used as a mapping key, an optimized approach is to use `defaultdict()` as following:

```
In [5]: from collections import defaultdict

In [6]: d = defaultdict(int)

In [7]: for sub in l:
   ...:     d[tuple(sub)] += 1
   ...:     

In [8]: d
Out[8]: defaultdict(int, {(1, 3, 2): 2, (1, 3, 5): 1})
```

This will give you a dictionary of your sub-lists as the key and their counts as the value.

Another way is to create your own dictionary object:

```
 In [9]: class customdict(dict):
    ...:        
    ...:     def __getitem__(self, key):
    ...:         try:
    ...:             val = super(customdict, self).__getitem__(key)
    ...:         except KeyError:
    ...:             self[key] = [*key, 0]
    ...:         else:
    ...:             val[-1] += 1
    ...:             self[key] = val
    ...:             return val
    ...:         
    ...:    

 In [10]: m = customdict()

 In [11]: for sub in l:
     ...:     m[tuple(sub)]
     ...:     

 In [12]: 

 In [12]: m
 Out[12]: {(1, 3, 2): [1, 3, 2, 2], (1, 3, 5): [1, 3, 5, 1]}

 In [13]: m.values()
 Out[13]: dict_values([[1, 3, 2, 2], [1, 3, 5, 1]])
```